# Unable to generate a controller of one table from a relational database C# Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I managed to generate a SQLite data model for C# In visual Studio 2019.

The database is a relational one with a couple of foreign keys.

When I try to generate a controller, I get this error:
[image]

I am willing to supply a bit more information if needed.
Is there a way to get the specified file the error is saying?

Comment: The error shows that you have a missing package which is `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Utils`
Have you tried to install it via `NuGet PackageManager`?

Comment: I'll try that and see if it works.

Comment: Works but I have another error but don't worry about it.